# Problem with invisible background in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to draw an arrow like the image below.

[image]

The code I generated is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\title{}
\author{ }
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) -- (-0.2, 1.5) -- (0.25,2.5) -- (0.7,1.5) -- (0.5,1.5) -- 
(0.5,0) -- (0,0) ;
\filldraw [gray] (0.25,0.5) circle (0.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I could not find a way to make the circle invisible inside the arrow. Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: Draw the circle first. Then fill and draw the arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just draw things from back to front, since you want to fill the arrow anyway.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw [black, line width=3mm] (-0.75,0.5) -- (1.25,0.5);
  \filldraw [gray,draw=black] (0.25,0.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \draw [draw=red!80!gray, top color=red!35, bottom color=red] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) -- (-0.2, 1.5) -- (0.25,2.5) -- (0.7,1.5) -- (0.5,1.5) -- 
  (0.5,0) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Note that you may find it easier if you put the centre of the circle at `(0,0)` as it makes it straightforward to ensure symmetry.

[image: arrow on circle on line]

Answer (score 4):

You could use layers as described in the "Layered graphics" section of the pgf manual. The idea is to first declare some layers (with the `\pgfdeclarelayer` macro) and then order them (with the `\pgfsetlayers`). The `main` layer is declared when loading the `tikz/pgf` package. It is the default layer. To use a declared layer, just put your code inside a `pgfonlayer` environment.

(Code adapted from @cfr nice answer)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
% Ordered layers (bottom to top)
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw[draw = red!80!gray, top color = red!35, bottom color = red] (0, 0) -- (0, 1.5) -- (-0.2, 1.5) -- (0.25, 2.5) -- (0.7, 1.5) -- (0.5, 1.5) -- (0.5, 0) -- cycle;
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[black, line width = 3mm] (-0.75, 0.5) -- (1.25, 0.5);
    \filldraw[gray, draw = black] (0.25, 0.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The main advantage of layers is that you can position background objects relative to foreground objects (defined earlier).